# How do I get these unordered lists next to each other?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, inline

How to get these lists (the unordered lists inside list items 1 till 4) next to each other with css3?

This is the code i have been using, i have been trying several methods but i can't seem to get the hang of it

```
<footer>

    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
            <ul>
                <li>Visie & Beleid</li>
                <li>Opbouw Studieprogramma</li>
                <li>Competenties</li>

            </ul>

        <li>2</li>
            <ul>
                <li>Mededelingen</li>
                <li>Uitagenda</li>
                <li>Propedeuse</li>

            </ul>

        <li>3</li>
            <ul>
                <li>Contact</li>
                <li>Blog</li>
                <li>Docenten</li>
                <li>Onderwijsbureau</li>

            </ul>


    </ul>
</footer>
```

Comment: This is not valid markup.  You cannot have <ul> tags beneath <ul> tags.  Check out nesting lists in this article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/ul

Answer (score 0):

Did you try putting the "inside" `<ul>`s into divs, and then applying styles to the `<div>`s to give them width, and then float them to the left?

Something like the following jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/msturdy/yJ2Kw/4/

I will admit that I'm not sure about whether it is a good idea to put a `<div>` inside a `<ul>`, but it works well here in Chrome and Firefox!

( EDIT: updated link to take into account the closing of the `</li>` tags after the nested `<ul>` )

Comment: I'm glad to see you put the nested <ul> into the <li> but the <div>s are still invalid and not necessary.  http://jsfiddle.net/yJ2Kw/5/

Comment: Good point... checked it out on the [w3 validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input), and educated myself :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the display property of the list items you want next ot each other to inline, like this:

```
ul ul li { display: inline; }
```